# Post data being overriden since upgrading from jQuery 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Since upgrading to the lastest version of jQuery from 1.4, my ajax posts no longer allow ?? (double question marks).  Instead they are replaced with something like jQuery15206629880418804291_1302038490086

Using Firebug, I can see the following data sent in a post:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            global: false
        });

this._xhrM = $.ajax({
            url: '/services/chatroomservice.asmx/SendReceive',
            data: '{"R": "??"}',
        success: function (results) {}
};
```

Sent over the wire as:

```
{"R": "jQuery15206629880418804291_1302038490086"}
```

I have tried setting the traditional to true and processData to false, both had no effect.

Comment: What about when you use `data: {"R": "??"}`, sending an actual JSON object? It may be that jQuery reckons that, when you're sending a string, since this should be a querystring, "??" is a safe substring to use for its own purposes. Evil, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `jsonp` option to `false`.  According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that should prevent `?` from being expanded to a function in jQuery 1.5+.

```
this._xhrM = $.ajax({
            url: '/services/chatroomservice.asmx/SendReceive',
            data: '{"R": "??"}',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (results) {}
});
```

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the value wasn't supplanted twice. This entire option is news to me; isn't it dangerous that it's enabled by default?

Comment: @Tomalak - I can only speculate, but having answered a number of questions for people who don't understand how jsonp works, it doesn't surprise me that they've automated the process so that now if you use `callback=?` on any AJAX query it defaults to jsonp and does the replacement (like it has for getJSON for awhile now).  Probably saves a lot of headaches for people following API examples.

Comment: Seems like a shame. Anyway, I will _definitely_ have to read up on this. Thanks for the implicit heads up!