# Uncomprehensible jQuery $.ajax() behavior when data contains consecutive question marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I hope this is clear enough, I have spent a lot of time trying to pin this problem down, so I may not have much left for writing a perfect question. Besides, this might have to go into a jQuery bug report, but I'd rather post it here first as I'm a relative JavaScript novice, so maybe I did something wrong...

I created the following piece of code to reproduce it. It uses PHP to echo back the received data to the browser, although it might be able to work without any PHP.

The problem can be reproduced in Firefox 4 and Chrome 10. You'll need the console to see what's happening.

Here's the code:

```
<?
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
if (isset($input) and !empty($input)) {
    echo $input;
    die();
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var jsonData = {
                    "something":"??"
                };
                jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);
                var onSuccess = function(data){
                    console.log("Ajax Success!");
                    console.log(data);
                }
                var onError = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log("Ajax Error: "+textStatus);
                    console.log("More info:");
                    console.log(errorThrown);           
                    console.log(jqXHR);         
                }
                console.log("Now sending this: "+jsonData+" through Ajax...");
                var ajaxCmd = {
                    "url"       : "test.php", 
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type"  : "POST",
                    "async" : false,
                    "error"     : onError,
                    "success"   : onSuccess,
                    "data"  : jsonData
                };
                $.ajax(ajaxCmd);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Check your JavaScript console...</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

When loaded, it throws some apparently unrelated parse error or exception (depending on the browser). The json that should be sent is {"something":"??"} but if you inspect it in the network tab of Firebug (or the Chrome equivalent) you'll see that "??" is being replaced by some jQuery string which looks like:
jQuery152026845051744021475_1303152126170

And that is what the server receives.

This problem only happens when there are two or more consecutive question marks in the value field inside the sent JSON object, even if there are other letters in there. With one question mark it seems to work. Also changing "dataType" to "text" fixes this. But I need all these features!

If you comment out "jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonData);" or "$.ajax(ajaxCmd);" the errors also miraculously disappear.

More info:

Chrome console output:

```
test.php:21Now sending this: {"something":"??"} through Ajax...
jquery.min.js:16Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
test.php:16Ajax Error: parsererror
test.php:17More info:
test.php:18jQuery15206220591682940722_1303153398797 was not called
test.php:19
Object
```

Firefox Firebug output:

```
Now sending this: {"something":"??"} through Ajax...
Ajax Error: parsererror
More info:
jQuery15206494160738701454_1303153492631 was not called
Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"something":"jQuery152...8701454_1303153492631"}", more...}
invalid label
{"something":"jQuery15206494160738701454_1303153492631"}
```

Comment: If you go to the Chrome console and perform the "stringify" on that object, what do you see?  When I do it, it works fine. (*edit* oh - well I see now that it works for you too ... )

Comment: You might want to check other code interaction. I can run this in the console and have it operate just fine: `var t = JSON.stringify({ something: "??" }); console.log(t);`.

Comment: The result of stringify is printed to the console before being sent to the ajax function in my script (see line "Now sending this..."). Apparently it results in {"something":"??"}. It doesn't look wrong to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17532149/763747 SO solution works for me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

jQuery uses `??` as a placeholder for the callback function when using `jsonp`. When it parses an Ajax request, and it finds the double questionmark (or more questionmarks), it automatically assumes that you are trying to use `jsonp`. When you set the content-type manually, it will ignore the questionmarks.

So, avoid the problem by using contentType:

```
$.ajax(
    url: "your-url.php",
    dataType: "json",                 // what you expect the server to return
    contentType: "application/json",  // what you are sending
    ...
);
```

For reference:

[jQuery Bugtracker: $.AJAX CHANGED THE POST CONTENT IF INCLUDE "??" (2 QUESTION MARK)](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12326)

Hopes it saves someone else from hours of debugging...

Comment: Perfect!  This should really be marked as the correct answer as it explains exactly why this particular issue presents itself, and also provides the correct fix.

Comment: It did save me hours indeed. Thank you!

Comment: Bravo ! Is there a way to put this answer as accepted ?

Comment: Today I faced the same issue and this was a time saving frustration killer, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your recommendations. I have made this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're not going to format the "data" value as a valid HTML query string, you shouldn't pre-stringify it. As you noted, if you don't call "JSON.stringify()" then it works.  That's because the library already knows to handle that for you.

Now, if you want to send your JSON string as a parameter itself to server side code that expects to decode some JSON, then you need to set it up as a parameter:

```
    $.ajax(url, {
      // ...
      data: { jsonParam: jsonData },
      // ...
    });
```

Now your server will see an HTTP request with a parameter called "jsonParam", and its value will be your JSON-stringified string.

Comment: That may work... I'll try. BTW I took my code from stackoverflow, and it used to work before I ran into consecutive question marks.

Comment: It works, thank. I still think this is not very elegant, and that it should not have crashed in such an inconsistent way... But you gave me a solution that works and I'm thankful, I have a job to do after all!

Comment: Well the problem is that the JSON text isn't properly encoded, so I'm not sure how it managed to work in the first place :-)

Answer (score 4):

Since none of the existing answers mentioned this. You can solve this issue by adding

```
jsonp: false
```

to your ajax requests setting.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer you're looking for is setting jsonp:false in the AJAX call options.  I had this exact same problem and fixed it by doing that.

Read the answer to this similar question for more details:
[Post data being overriden since upgrading from jQuery 1.4 to 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558893/post-data-being-overriden-since-upgrading-from-jquery-1-4-to-1-5)

Answer (score 2):

I have a such problem in 1.5.2.
It's jQuery bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417.
You can update to 1.6.4 or do like this:
In jQuery function "jQuery.ajaxPrefilter"
changed:

```
var dataIsString = ( typeof s.data === "string" );
```

by

```
var inspectData = s.contentType === "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" &&
        ( typeof s.data === "string" );
```

and changed this variable in below "if" condition like this:

```
if ( s.dataTypes[ 0 ] === "jsonp" ||
        originalSettings.jsonpCallback ||
        originalSettings.jsonp != null ||
        s.jsonp !== false && ( jsre.test( s.url ) ||
                dataIsString && jsre.test( s.data ) ) ) {
                inspectData && jsre.test( s.data ) ) ) {
```

I took this fix form jQuery 1.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

Exact same issue with jQuery 1.71, double question mark and some crazy string gets inserted.

Was able to fix it by removing

```
dataType: 'JSON'
```

from the ajax command and it magically stopped doing it.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an encoding problem. If your data is not in UTF-8 format (like MS Word or something) this can happen.

Comment: "??" was translated to "jQuery152026845051744021475_1303152126170" before being handed to PHP so there was something else at play. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Escaping the values with `encodeURIComponent` did the job!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Specifying "contentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8" solves this issue.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    "url": url,
    "data": JSON.stringify(payload),
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "contentType":"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "success": function(data) {

    },
    "error": function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
});
```