# Submitting jQuery.ajax data with string containing "???" it changes value to "jQuery19107363727174233645_1373301489648?"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Page side javascript:

```
var model = {"NumberOfCPUs":"2","NumberOfCores":"4","OSType":"Linux","OSVersion":"???"};

        var id = 0;
        var success = false;
        //send to server:
        $.ajax(
            {
                async: false,
                data: JSON.stringify(model),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                url: serverSideURL

            });
```

The contents of the request that actually gets sent to the server:

```
{"NumberOfCPUs":"2","NumberOfCores":"4","OSType":"Linux","OSVersion":"jQuery19107363727174233645_1373301489648?"}
```

What is happening? Is the string "???" some sort of special control word or something in jQuery?

Thanks.

Comment: `processData:false` will fix this most likely.

Comment: Just curious: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Why are you submitting ??? anyway? Why not just null or a single ?

Answer (score 11):

If I read through the comments of the bugs in the other answers, the *real* problem lies in the fact that you stringify your json-string before passing it to `data`. `data` expects either a `String` containing a query (e.g. `"a=asdf&b=qwer"` or an `Object` containing the keys and values that it will turn into a query). You are instead passing something like `'{"a":"asdf","b":"qwer"}'`, a `String` containing a stringified array that is not a query. It somehow manages to convert in data the server understands, but apparently triggers that bug/feature too.

**Solution 1**

If you want to access the data via `$_POST['a']` to get key `"a"` in your JSON-object:

```
$.ajax( {
    async: false,
    data: model, //Pass the Array itself to the function
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: serverSideURL
});
```

([Source; Cowboy on jQuery bugs](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417#comment:8))

**Solution 2**

If you want to retrieve the JSON-string:

```
$.ajax( {
    async: false,
    data: {
      "MyLilString": JSON.stringify( model )
    }
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: serverSideURL
});
```

In this case `$_POST["MyLilString"]` contains the serialized JSON, which you can use `json_decode()` on.

([Source; Ajpiano on jQuery bugs](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417#comment:9))

**Another sugestion**

Another suggestion I did extract from the comments (but I am now unable to find -_-') is to set `jsonp` to `false`.

```
$.ajax( {
    async: false,
    data: model
    dataType: "json",
    type: "post",
    url: serverSideURL,
    jsonp: false
});
```

This should stop jQuery from inserting the callback function into the request body too.

Comment: thanks for the good explantion, the official jquery issues are mentioned here: [link](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/878) and here: [link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/1799)

Answer (score 3):

> ?? is used as the callback name placeholder in the data for jsonp
>   requests. So, finding it, jQuery will "promote" your request as jsonp.

jquery bug tracker, [**ticket #12326**](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12326)

Use this property

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a [known bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8417):

> When posting AJAX and the data has "??" is formats it to
>   jQuery?

It's marked fixed even though in the comments on the bug it's clearly never been fixed. The issue should be reopened.

Workarounds apparently include changing your JSON line to the following:

```
var model = {NumberOfCPUs:"2",NumberOfCores:"4",OSType:"Linux",OSVersion:"???"};
```

and allowing it to be serialized. This way it won't trigger the regex that's causing the double question marks to be replaced.