# send array variable along with form.serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using below code to send data for processing in PHP,

```
var quick1_ids = jQuery.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
  return item.quick_id;
});
```

and to to send this variable as AJAX,

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: baseURL + "myurl/function",
  data: {quick_id:quick1_ids},
  type: "POST",
  success:function(data){....}
})
```

In this code everything works fine and data parsed to server as below,

```
quick_id[]:11
quick_id[]:12
```

Now problem,
I want to pass same quick1_id variable along with form data like below,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: baseURL + "myurl/function_1",
    data: $("#quickreport_fm").serialize() + "&quick_id=" + quick1_ids,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){...}
```

But with i use this along with serialize it not passing as array but goes as object,

```
quick_id: 11, 12
```

How can i pass it as `quick_id[]:11` and `quick_id[]:12` in form.serialize()?

Thanks

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532018/submitting-jquery-ajax-data-with-string-containing-it-changes-value-to-jq/17533499#17533499 (well, the answer, not so much the question itself)

Comment: y not add a hidden input before the ajax call

Comment: @Iceman, quick_id is not a part of form, those values are coming from selected rows of datatables

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my PHP code that makes the array:

```
$quick_array = explode(",",$this->input->post('quick_id'));
```

This will help me to do the processing of the array.