# What is difference between 'headers:{"Content-Type":XXX}' and 'contentType:XXX'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery.ajax provides `contentType` property to define request data type. 
Also, `content-type` could be set by `headers` property.

Any difference between them?

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    ...
});
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    data: data,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    ...
});
```

Comment: have you observed any difference in the request that is sent?

Comment: IMO this should be the same - `contentType` will be added to headers as `Content-Type` before request is made.

Answer (score 4):

From the jQuery source code. The only usage of `contentType` option is:

```
if (s.data && s.hasContent && s.contentType !== false || options.contentType) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", s.contentType);
}
```

The only usage of `headers` option is:

```
for (i in s.headers) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader(i, s.headers[i]);
}
```

The only difference is that when using `contentType`, jQuery does an extra check to see if your request has any actual data. If not, the `content-type` header is not added to the headers.

*PS: I checked only the code of  [jQuery2.1.3](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.ajax), but I doubt its different in any other version*

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old, but today we faced an issue related to this topic.

The behavior of jQuery is different between setting `contentType` property or `content-type` header if your data contains consecutive questions marks.

Based on the following link, `contentType` property is the best option. Otherwise, jQuery will assumes that you are trying to use `jsonp`.

[Uncomprehensible jQuery $.ajax() behavior when data contains consecutive question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707619/uncomprehensible-jquery-ajax-behavior-when-data-contains-consecutive-questio#answer-17660503)