# SAPUI5 oData requests with 2 question marks

Tags: jquery, encoding, utf-8, odata, sapui5

I have an application with mock server.

All requests supports utf-8

```js
// mockserver.js part
var fnResponse = function (iErrCode, sMessage, aRequest) {
    aRequest.response = function (oXhr) {
        oXhr.respond(iErrCode, {"Content-Type": "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}, sMessage);
    };
};
```

If i send some data to dackend with only 1 question mark

```
test?
```

then after data update i have still *test?*

But by send of *test??* i receive test something like *testjQuery223039144209666350105_1579678479568*

by send of five question marks, the first to changes to jQuery... and other 3 are still in text.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the following on your request:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Why? [Because ?? is a placeholder for a callback function in jsonp.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707619/uncomprehensible-jquery-ajax-behavior-when-data-contains-consecutive-questio)